# Oracle stricty like operator

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table where some columns could have values like this

- %YZW
- %

I have the "Oracle Wildcard" in the table because i will access it in this way:

```
where myVal like field_1
```

If for example myVal is XYZW , the previus like will match both:

1. First match is because i have % follow YZW
2. Second match because % will match anything

There is a way to say "if myVal is exactly explicit in the field, consider only it?"

I try to explain better with an example:

- myVal = XYZW -> Shoud match only with %YZW (any records with stricty %)
- myVal = YZ -> Should match only with %

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your question.  YZ will only match % in the example you give.  It won't match %YZW because 'YZ' doesn't have a W at the end.

Comment: The problem is with XYZW, this will match bot: %YZW and %. I would like to have only %YZW

Answer (score 1):

You can create an order for the comparisons that you run.

```
create table match_tests (val varchar2(10), priority number);
insert into match_tests values ('%YZW',1);
insert into match_tests values ('%',2);
```

This priority column here specifies that you want the '%YZW' match to be considered highest priority followed by '%' as the next highest.

Then you can query like this:

```
select min(priority)
from match_tests
where 'XYZW' like val;
```

The result is 1.

Or this:

```
select min(priority)
from match_tests
where 'YZ' like val;
```

The result is 2.